# Bootstrap 3.0 and Visual Studio 2013 SPA Template CSS Error

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I created a new Web App using VS2013 and chose the (default)SPA Template.  Once created I have two CSS Errors, technically for the same thing in both the min and reg version, in bootstrap.css.  It goes as follows:

`CSS: Unexpected end of selector`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  @-ms-viewport {
    width: 320px;
  }
}
```

In particular it is pointing at the 2nd line of that code.  I read the Bootstrap Docs and couldn't find anything directly referencing this issue.  See here -->[Bootstrap FAQ](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration)

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT**

Just to reiterate: This issue happens upon project creation.  I haven't done anything yet...

Comment: Not sure, check in your editor configuration if it treats cssLevel3.

Comment: maybe it's trying to validate as css2.1?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! How do I check either of those though?

Comment: See this page : http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#bootstrap explaining how to use Bootstrap with vd2013

Comment: That link doesn't have any information on the default templates having any errors.  Just general usage info.  I don't have an issue with using Bootstrap with vs 2013.  I have an issue with Bootstrap having css errors in the default template in vs 2013.  I haven't done anything yet, it's broken at the start.